# Can my team members use a specific runner in GitLab registered for a project by me (maintainer) in my laptop even when I shut down my laptop?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

We as a team are working in a branch in GitLab. I (maintainer) registered a specific runner for this project in my laptop to execute the pipeline. Can my team members use this runner registered by me even when I shut down my system? What happens in case of I registered my runner within docker ?

Comment: Is the machine you registered your own system? If yes, then it would be unavailable. More details are needed to answer this question - it's not clear.

Answer (score 3):

If a machine is turned off it cannot execute a pipeline.